# Where can I ask questions about an IT language without printing code of what I've done

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I wanted to ask a question about something I have no clue about in java,
the subject was:

> Would it be possible to create a class during runtime execution?

I was curious about it, but I haven't coded anything, so I have no code to show to fill the quality of a post on stackoverflow.

So I ask here, is there any "stack" site related to IT where I could ask this type of question ?

Comment: IMO its not the fact that you have no code that makes the question off-topic, but that you ask it as a yes/no question which is pretty much not useful on any stack site. Remember that it is not about you and what you want to know, its about the question and answers. If you wonder about this subject then you have done research and can show what you have found out, at the very least.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608704/java-generate-class-file-at-runtime and similar.  Also, search the internets and read.  Lots of info out there.  Come back when you have a question about the process.  Also, don't ask yes/no questions.  They suck.  Always think:  What are you trying to do?  What have you done to accomplish this goal?  What was the result?  Why is the result not working for you?

Comment: The title can be answered by Yes/No but in the content of course i ask some more specific question. Anyway i asked and i had a proper answer, ty.